# Open function from CSV library is generating a file does not exist error

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to open and read information from a CSV file in order to perform some analysis on it. The file name comes from a user entering the name of the CSV but when I enter an existing CSV the error occurs.

```
output_str = "Write in the file name"
fname = raw_input(output_str)

infile = ['(touch ID)', '(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)', '(frames)', '(mm)', '(x)', 
'(y)', '(raw x)', '(raw y)']
extraRows = 17
```

I've tried to implement it with its full path and that generates the same error.

```
#Extraction for data
with open(fname, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    data = {}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the error/stacktrace in your post?

Comment: Could you give us an idea of the kind of file names you're inputting? You're probably not correctly inputting the absolute path

Comment: I have been getting this error when I copy the path directly from the copy path function in windows[Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '"C:\\Users\\student\\AppData\\LocalLow\\University of Michigan\\Boids\\DiagnosticData\\2018_07_24-12_30_31_033--000.csv"'

Comment: Aside: even if you had the right path, that code wouldn't work for a different reason.  You're not passing the file object to `DictReader`.

Comment: I have also tried inputting just the file name and got this error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2018_07_24-12_30_033--000.csv'.

Comment: @DSM Thanks I forgot to change the name of CsvFile